# EF Core Navigation Property and mapping profile

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

I'm trying to apply mapping to navigation property but I got an error. I have two classes that contain a navigation property One-To-Many.

```
public class Contractor : Entity<string>
{
      public virtual Collection<DocsVat> DocsVats { get; set; }
}


public class DocsVat : Entity<Guid>
{
   public  Contractor Contractor { get; set; }
}
```

The configuration is :

```
public class DocsVatEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfigurationBase<DocsVat>
{
protected override void ConfigureEntity()
{
        Builder.ToTable("DocsVat", "VAT");
        Builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Builder.HasOne(p => p.Contractor).WithMany(p=>p.DocsVats).HasForeignKey(p => 
        p.ContractorNo).IsRequired();
        Builder.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsRequired();
}
}
```

and Mapping profile:

```
 public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Entities.DocsVat, DocsVatDto>();
        CreateMap<DocsVatDto, Entities.DocsVat>();
        CreateMap<FnPurchaseDetail, DocsVatDto>();

        CreateMap<Entities.DocsVat, DocsVatDto>().ForMember(dto => dto.Contractor, conf => 
        conf.MapFrom(ent => ent.Contractor.Id));
    }
}
```

The error I've got:

```
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
DocsVatDto -> DocsVat
###.ApplicationServices.Doc.DocsVAT.Dto.DocsVatDto -> ###.Entities.DocsVat

Type Map configuration:
DocsVatDto -> DocsVat
###.ApplicationServices.Doc.DocsVAT.Dto.DocsVatDto -> ###.Entities.DocsVat

Destination Member:
Contractor
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be with [Automapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances) configuration, not entity framework. You would need to post a more detailed error message, but apparently Automapper is trying to map the property `Contractor` of `DocsVat` but it can't find a mapping configuration for it.

Either ignore that property when configuring the mapping of `DocsVatDto => DocsVat` or create a map for converting a `ContractorDto => Contractor`